# How can stock files like .xlsx in elasticsearch, but with type upload. just indtroduce path?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have an excel file: fille1.xlsx, I want to index it in elasticsearch, without store all pieces of information but just the path of the file, The file is stored in my hard disc. And after, to access on, I upload the file.

is this possible?

This solution permits me to search the files in elasticsearch_database.

for example, search: 'fille' and return a list of files that the name is beginning with 'fille'..without access on information that files contains, just a possibility to upload it and open it with excel.

Comment: Yes - you could write a script to look at the contents of the directory you're interested in, and index a single document per file simply containing the full path (if needed) and filename.  The example query you indicated would then return the results you're looking for.  If you provide an example of what you've already tried and any errors, more help could be provided in addressing any areas you're encountering problems or errors.

Comment: Hello, i did not understand your answer. can you give me a link? or an exemple. than illustrate my exemple.